# How to schedule biweekly SSRS subscription on 2017 report server

Tags: sql, reporting-services, report, subscription, ssrs-2017

I would like my report to be sent biweekly on a Monday. Right now, I created two different subscriptions that sends the report on every 2nd and 4th week. I am not sure it would be accurate considering, I would like the send the report Monday after Pay period ends. What's a best way to approach to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subscription can be created by Week and scheduled to repeat after 2 weeks. Monday can be selected as the day.

[image]

The schedule will show *Every Monday of every two weeks*.

[image]

Comment: I am not able to select the days when I choose the week. Its only letting me deselect one day.